# getPath() Dijkstra's Algorithm in C

Tags: c

http://www.algolist.com/code/c/Dijkstra's_algorithm

This is the codes for getting the shortest path. I don't know how to implement the getpath() in the said implementation.

If you have better Dijkstra's Algorithm implementation in C. It would mean a lot  to me.

```
void getpath(int s, int t, int pred[]) { 
     int current = t;
     while (current != s) { 
         printf("%d -> ", current); current = pred[current]; 
     }
     printf("%d\n",current); 
}
```

Comment: well what have you tried? Are you encountering any errors? Do you have any code?

Comment: void getpath(int s, int t, int pred[]) {
    int current = t;

    while (current != s) {
        printf("%d -> ", current);
        current = pred[current];
    }

    printf("%d\n",current);
}

Comment: It is difficult to read code in the comment section.  Can you edit your question and put code with your question?

Answer (score 0):

[in this link](http://www.algolist.com/code/c/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)    make cost as global variable of 2d array of type int and call `shortpath(cost,preced,distance);`
in the `main()`

after that in the `cost[][]` 2d array will have paths along with length  select the shortest among them

before applying it  i suggest you  understand Dijkstra's algo first here is the link [Dijkstra's algo[2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nVYi3o161A)
or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nVYi3o161A